# title is not displayed in a Checkbox in Titanium

Tags: android, checkbox, titanium, title

I've a routine to create checkboxes depending on a tag of an xml file.

The title of the checkbox is not displayed on the screen.

```
switch (items.item(i).getAttribute("type")) 
    {
        case 'checkbox':

                var tempViewCheckBoxes = Ti.UI.createView({backgroundColor:'white', layout:'vertical'});
                var tempRespuestas = items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("Respuesta");

                for (var j=0;j<tempRespuestas.length;j++) 
                {
                    var checkBox = Titanium.UI.createSwitch({
style:Titanium.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
                                                     title:tempRespuestas.item(j).text,
                                                        value:false,
                                                        visible : true,
                                                        top:10,
                                                        left:10,
                                                        height : 'auto',
                                                        width : 'auto'
                                                });

                    var tempLabelCheckBox = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                            text: tempRespuestas.item(j).text,
                            font:{fontSize:30},
                            top:'30',
                            left:'10',
                            textAlign:'center',
                            color:'black',
                            width:'auto',
                            height:'auto'
                          });

                    tempViewCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
                    tempViewCheckBoxes.add(tempLabelCheckBox);

                }
                tempView.add(tempViewCheckBoxes);
                break;
       }

    scrollView.addView(tempView);
}
```

While I can see the Label displaying the correct text, i do not see the text displayed in the checkbox.

Could anybody explain me why the text is not displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as adding the color: '#000', I believed the default colour would be black and not white.

```
var checkBox = Titanium.UI.createSwitch({
                                       style:Titanium.UI.Android.SWITCH_STYLE_CHECKBOX,
                                       title:tempRespuestas.item(j).text,
                                       value:false,
                                                    color: '#000',
                                                    visible : true,
                                                    top:10,
                                                    left:10,
                                                    height : 'auto',
                                                    width : 'auto'
                                            });
```